# IE8 showing a margin but shouldn't

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, margin

In IE8 my header looks like a bottom margin is set, yet margins are set to 0px. I've set a border property to test this.

I'm using DIV tags not HTML5 header, nav, etc.

Now that I'm looking at this picture, I'm noticing an extra pixel on the right as well.

```
#header
{
    margin:  0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:   800px;
    height:  200px;
    border:  1px solid red; /* test */
}

#nav
{
    margin:  0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border:  1px solid black; /* test */
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show your markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the grey colour in the header coming from? If it's an image, you might want to check that its dimensions match those in your CSS definition (i.e. 800px x 200px). Otherwise, try removing any margins on the image.

Without seeing your full HTML structure, it's difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: <div id="header">
  <a href="">
   <img src="images/testheader.jpg" width="800px" height="200px" alt="test"/> 
  </a>
 </div>

and

*
{
 margin:    0;
 padding:   0;
}

Comment: The grey color is in image testheader.jpg. dimensions match perfectly. Why else would it work in everything except IE?

Comment: Try adding `a img { border: none; }` to your CSS.

Comment: Then without seeing the full HTML structure, there's very little we can do to help more I'm afraid.

Comment: I had a silly error in CSS that I figured out myself. But thank you guys for all your help.